# Softening borders with Photoshop CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to soften the edges of an image similar to this image:

[image]

I tried using the blur tool but nothing was happening.

Can anyone tell me how to reproduce the results of that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the canvas with your chosen colour, then:

1. Select > All
2. Select > Modify > Border... (width 3px)
3. Select > Modify > Feather... (width 3px)
4. Select > Edit > Cut, to delete the selection.